# Google charts remove array from inside the main array of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I have the following script:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540],
      ['2009',  1030,      540],
      ['2011',  1,      677]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    function swicthGraphType(){
      $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){

        var thisValue = $(this).attr("data-lineType");

        console.log(data.Ad[0]);

        if(thisValue == ""){
          options.curveType = '';
        }
        if(thisValue == "function"){
          options.curveType = 'function';
        }

        chart.draw(data, options);


      });
    }

     swicthGraphType();

  }
```

I would like to create a click function which removes temporally one of the arrays for example:

```
data.Ad[0]
```

and put it back in the graph when I want. Basically I would need a function which I can use to show what I need to see in the graph

Comment: Perhaps you can add a jsfiddle.net? That way people not familiar with google charts can have a hack and a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution A:**
Add a array variable `var blackList = []`,
write a filter function, `function dataFilter() {}`, which loop each element of your data, if it's not in the black list, then add it to a new array, finally, return the new array.
then use the new array to fill your chart instead of you original data.
you modify the black list variable, to decide which to filter or not.

**Solution B (base on A):**
**Use object instead of array for black list:**

If you think modify the black list as an array is not easy, then you can create the black list as an object, use properties of object to store your black list, the name of property is year e.g. 2006, the value of property is your data of that year.

Add/override a black list element: `blackList[2006] = ['2006', 660, 1120];`
Read/detect a black list element: `blackList[2006]`
Delete a black listelement: `delete blackList[2006]`